# How to get comma after close bracket in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hi guys i want to have comma after close bracket in notepad++

```
(17.369217, 78.458492)(17.369216, 78.458486)(17.369121, 78.458329)(17.36894, 78.458023)
```

I want the result as (17.369217, 78.458492),(17.369216, 78.458486),(17.369121, 78.458329),(17.36894, 78.458023),

Comment: So do a search/replace?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get?

Comment: I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the editor's built-in replace capability:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to get the Replace dialog
2. In the `Find what` input, add `)`
3. In the `Replace with` input, add `),`
4. Ensure the `Search Mode` is set to `Normal`
5. Then click the `Replace All` button